# jenkins doesn't generate the build automatically using local git repository

Tags: jenkins

In  my system i am using local git repository and **jenkins server**,I clone the **bitbucket repository** into my local git repository and perform all the operations it does well.

I would like to generate the bulids automatically whenever there is push is going from local git to **bitbucket** for that i give the git repository url in the source code management and mark the build trigger `**when a change is pushed to bitbucket**
Later i apply and press save.

Now I did some modifications in local git and pushed it also,it is successfully pushed and data is updated in **bitbucket** also but in **jenkins** there is no build

`can any one please help to me.`

Comment: Are you using the build trigger "Poll SCM"? Or am I missing something...

Comment: NO I am not using that, I am using build trigger "Build when a change is pushed to BitBucket"

Comment: Sorry - I'm not familiar with it...

Comment: k can you tell me you i can work using POLL SCM trigger

Comment: Are you using the [BitBucket plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BitBucket+Plugin)?

Comment: Yeah,can you please help to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to poll, you must configure BitBucket to notify your Jenkins when something happens. These are called "hooks". You can read about them at https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Manage+Bitbucket+hooks and there is a whole section on how to configure a hook for Jenkins.